# java.util.EmptyStackException

Tags: java, stack

I have the following part of code to initialize an array of stack:

```
vDec.setRoute(new Stack[vDec.getIndexes().length]);
for(i=0;i<vDec.getIndexes().length;i++){
    vDec.getRoute()[i]=new Stack<>();
}
```

I get `java.util.EmptyStackException` when I am checking if it is empty inside a `while` loop but not before it. So for this part:

```
if(vDec.getRoute()[(int)IndexVeh.peek()].isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("it works");
}
while((cDec.getVisitedBy()[crtCust]==-1)&&(!Distance.empty())){
    if(vDec.getRoute()[(int)IndexVeh.peek()].isEmpty()){
        do something
```

I first get as output `it works` and then the exception.

Comment: 1) Do you know exactly which line that exception is thrown on?
2) Do you ever modify `IndexVeh` inside the `do something` block?

Comment: I get it on the second `if(vDec.getRoute()[(int)IndexVeh.peek()].isEmpty())`. Yes but all the values of the stack IndexVeh are in the range of the array of stacks.

Comment: But that's not what it is saying.  It is saying that the stack is empty.  Trust the JVM.  At the point that exception is being thrown, the Stack in question >>is<< empty.  You need to figure out why that is so; i.e. what is the flaw in your reasoning / evidence gathering that is misleading you.

Comment: So I have an empty `IndexVeh` stack not the other one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line

```
     if(vDec.getRoute()[(int)IndexVeh.peek()].isEmpty())
```

You will get an `EmptyStackException` if and only if `IndexVeh` is empty when that line is executed.